# How to repair an Error 4059 on calling the OrderModify() function | MQL4?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

My **`EA`** comes up with an error code of `4059`
**which means**
that the **`OrderModify()`** function is apparently not allowed in (back) testing.

Is there any way in which this could be allowed at all?

All I'm wanting to do is change the position to breakeven, when it gets 100 pips "to the good"

```
PrintFormat( "TKT[%.2d]OP:[%7.5f]SL:[%7.5f]CurrentPrice:[%7.5f]Stoplevel:[%.3d]FreezeLevel:[%.3d]",
              aTicket,
              anOpenPrice,
              aCurrentSL,
              anAskPrice,
              stopLevel,
              freezeLevel
              );
SellMod = OrderModify( aTicket,
                       NormalizeDouble( anOpenPrice, Digits ),
                       NormalizeDouble( aNewSLPrice, Digits ),
                       NormalizeDouble( aNewTpPrice, Digits ),
                       0,
                       sellcolor
                       );
SendMail( "Notification of Order Modification for Ticket#"
         + IntegerToString( OrderTicket(), 10 ),
           "Good news! Order Ticket#"
         + IntegerToString( OrderTicket(), 10 )
         + "has been changed to breakeven"
           );
if (  !SellMod )
{     PrintFormat( "Order modification for ticket %10d has failed modify the order under the Error Code# %5d. Check MQL4 Documentation",
                   aTicket,
                   GetLastError()
                   );
      result = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### `4059 ERR_FUNC_NOT_ALLOWED_IN_TESTING`
is clear,
 not the source of it
 though

> Function is not allowed in testing mode
> **`[ HIDDEN REMAINS _WHERE_ + _WHY_ IT IS REPORTED]`** :)

So,
modify a few details on **Error-Detection**
so as to get back to the riding saddle and **to get the things back under your full control:**

```
 .
 ..
 ...
 // ======================================== .ASSUME NOTHING       ; the best
 //                                                                      advice
 //                                                                      ever :)
 //                //     ALWAYS (pre-clear) 
 GetLastError();   /* _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  AND   ERR_SYSREG, 0   ; CLEAR SYSREG
                                                                   ; (
                                                                   ; prevents 
                                                                   ; from reading
                                                                   ; a value from
                                                                   ; some "old"
                                                                   ; error-code
                                                                   ; on a "next"
                                                                   ; GetLastError
                                                                   ; call
                                                                   ; )
                   */
 OrderModify(...); //                        CALL  _OrderModify

 gotLastERROR =    //                        MOV   VAR, ERR_SYSREG ; CATCH ERR
 GetLastError();   // _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  AND   ERR_SYSREG, 0   ; CLEAR SYSREG

 // ---------------------------------------- ( a main-effect )
 //                                          ( VAR has this _FUN call error-code )

 // +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+- ( a side-effect )
 //                                          ( ERR_SYSREG is clear AGAIN )
 ...
 ..
 .
```

With a similarly systematic approach to **Error-Detection** you will soon realise the root cause of the observed problem and any **Error-Handling** will only start to have sense.

Most probably, the error originates a few `SLOC`-s lower, under your `OrderModify()` call, where **`SendMail()`** call appears, in spite of the fact, that HELP explicitly says:

> **`Note`**
> Sending can be prohibited in settings, email address can be omitted as well. For the error information call `GetLastError()`.
>   `SendMail()` function does not work in the <kbd>Strategy Tester</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

**`OrderModify()`** does **NOT** generate error `4059`.
That error comes from `SendMail()`. Documentation states that:
https://docs.mql4.com/common/sendmail

Comment: Exactly, Joseph Lee, you might have noticed, that the May 4th post has stated that already altogether with some didactic reasoning around this root-cause.